# Commutativity of tensor product: $(|A\rangle \langle A|)^{\otimes 2} = |A\rangle^{\otimes 2}\langle A|^{\otimes 2}$

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I was wondering if the following equality is true:

\begin{equation}
(|A\rangle \langle A|)^{\otimes 2} = |A\rangle^{\otimes 2}\langle A|^{\otimes 2}
\end{equation}

If so, how do I go about proving it?

Comment: Apply the operators on both sides to vectors of the form $|\phi\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$.